# org-mind-map unable to find flatten and dot command

Tags: debugging, path

I get the following error when running org-mind-map.

[image]

Paths the each are as follows:

```
$ which unflatten 
/usr/local/bin/unflatten

$ which dot 
/usr/local/bin/dot
```

How to tell org-mind-map to access them at these places?

Comment: Add `"/usr/local/bin"` to the `PATH` environment variable.

You can do that in your init file with the following Elisp snippet.


    `(setenv "PATH" (concat "/usr/local/bin:" (getenv "PATH")))`

Afterwards Emacs should find `unflatten` and `dot`.

Comment: What OS are you doing this on? Because if it's Mac, I'd use suggest using [`expand-path-from-shell`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell). It will do what @Tobias said automatically if you set it up correctly

Comment: Yeap, It's a Mac